# Mysql - Get intersection of rows in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this simple table (called `jobs_criterias`) :

```
+-----------+---------+-------------+
| id        | job_id  | criteria_id |
+-----------+---------+-------------+
|       101 | 4       | 3           |
|       105 | 6       | 5           |
|       130 | 8       | 5           |
|       132 | 9       | 5           |
|       133 | 6       | 7           |
|       150 | 7       | 8           |
|       160 | 8       | 9           |
+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

I want to find the `job_id` which have same `criteria_id`.

For example, I want to search `job_id` for `criteria_id IN (5, 7)`. It should return 6 with the sample data (only `job_id` = 6 matches both `criteria_ids`)

After some searchs, I use this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   job_id
FROM jobs_criterias jc1
   INNER JOIN jobs_criterias jc2 USING(job_id)
WHERE jc1.criteria_id = 5 AND jc2.criteria_id = 7
```

It works but this query is not easily extensible. I use query builder from PHP framework and it's hard to build this kind of queries.

Is there any simpler way to achieve this ?

Comment: Assuming there is a ```UNIQUE``` constraint on ```(job_id, criteria_id)``` (or the other way around), you should be able to remove the ```DISTINCT```. What exactly is your problem, what do you want to avoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a grouping query to count the number of `criteria_id` which  a given `job_id` matches, selecting only those that match all of them:

```
SELECT job_id
FROM jobs_criterias
WHERE criteria_id IN (5, 7)
GROUP BY job_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT criteria_id) = 2
```

Output

```
6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kcq6cZw58zWCqHJ4ACBTKU/0)

Comment: Very nice, works for me. Thanks

Comment: @VincentDecaux no worries. Note that as was said in the comments to the question, if you can only have one entry for a given `(job_id, criteria_id)` combination, you don't need the `DISTINCT` in the `COUNT`.

Comment: Yes you are right, this DISTINCT made mistakes on my initial query